# UILabel top alignment with multiline

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uicollectionview, vertical-alignment

I have a `UILabel` with 4 lines in a `UICollectionView`. When there are fewer than 4 rows, I want the text to be on the top and not in the centre.

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the solution

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            yourLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            [yourLabel sizeToFit];


        });
```

Comment: it actually works.. I can't understand why as this was already the main thread

Answer (score 1):

In Swift:

```
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByClipping 
yourLabel.text = yourString.stringByAppendingString("\n\n\n\n")
```